# What's the effect of removing @GeneratedValue from the Id on the performance

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jdbc, eclipse-rcp, tomcat8

I'm working on a RCP-application, which communicates with an a Tomcat-server using Rest. Since we've gotten more and more data, the load/copy-routines are slowly but surly becoming obsolete. It's taking me sometimes minutes to execute some copy-operation. So I'm looking for some advise, how to speed up my routines.

Here are the technologies I'm using:

1. RCP-Client (e4-plattform)
2. Tomcat8-Server
3. Oracle-DB
4. JDBC as API with Hibernate
5. Rest

First thing first. I checked the entities and the pretty much all look like the code below

```
@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(name = "CHECKITEM_SEQ", sequenceName = "CHECKITEM_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
public class CheckItem extends AbstractTreeNode implements Serializable,Cloneable {...}
```

I figured by copying data (which are most of the time over 200K per operation) since I use them as primary key,

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "CHECKITEM_SEQ", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
```

the DB must generate per object a sequence and check the constraint on it, So I was wondering how much performance I would gain, if I remove the Sequence since i don't really use/need them in the DB. Now my questions:

1. Is there anything that speaks against removing a constraint(primary key in this particularly case) in DB?
2. Has anyone more/better suggestions how to increase the performance of DB for such operations?
3. Can I have a tutorial or document, which can help me through this process?

I hope, i was clear enough and I will appreciate any kind of help. thanks already.

Comment: Does anything else besides your process insert into the table? If so, you will need that sequence object to coordinate generated IDs. Also, removing constraints will not make a load process go from minutes to single-digit seconds. Loading might be fractionally faster, but at the cost of who knows what queries and the risk of corrupted data.

Comment: The ID isn't used anywhere in the client. Client uses UUIDs for object's identification. So I have no concern what so ever on removing them. I guess my question is, how much performance I can gain by doing that and if it's worth to spend the time refactoring the code.

Comment: The client might not use it, but are there user queries, views, reports, foreign keys, other non-Java processes going on? A table should always have a primary key, although if it's just a generated number that nothing references then I agree it's not useful. I don't know how this UUID thing fits into your data model though. Also you could have the database generate the ID automatically on insert (trigger in Oracle 11g or earlier, identity column from 12c) and leave it out of the load process altogether.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with using `@GeneratedValue` identifiers is that in order for Hibernate to place the new entity into the Persistence Context (the first level cache), it must know the identifier.  So when you're using `IDENTITY` or `SEQUENCE` based identifiers, this can impact the JDBC driver from being able to adequately batch insert operations.

For example, you illustrated that most of your entities use the following sequence generation:

```
@SequenceGenerator(
   name = "CHECKITEM_SEQ", 
   sequenceName = "CHECKITEM_SEQ", 
   allocationSize = 1)
```

So whenever a persist operation for an entity happens, you're telling the sequence generator to only generate one value, so the JDBC communication looks like this:

```
1. Get Next Sequence
2. Insert
3. Get Next Sequence
4. Insert
5. Get Next Sequence
6. Insert
```

As seen here, we cannot batch the insert operations because we must fetch the identifier for each insert operation before the insert operation can happen.  One solution to minimize that impact and deal with batch inserts is to use a larger `allocationSize`.

```
1. allocationSize=10 -> Get Next 10 sequences
2 - 11. Perform 10 inserts in batch
Repeat
```

As you can see here the driver can do 10 inserts in a batch, Hibernate allocates the sequences in batches on 10 and so the inserts can happen much faster.

Obviously this comes with a small drawback, if you allocate 10 sequences but the remaining batch only needs to insert 6 entities; you've wasted 4 sequence values but you gain the performance from being able to support doing jdbc batch inserts.

The next logical step would be to determine if you can eliminate the use of a `@GeneratedValue` all together as that would given you the maximum performance with batch inserts for your copy operations; however that may not be possible with your data model.  In the past when I dealt with moving large volumes of  data, I tried to define the primary key based on natural keys from the data without involving a surrogate key if possible.

Feel free to read more about JDBC batch operations [here](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-customize-the-jdbc-batch-size-for-each-persistence-context-with-hibernate/).

Comment: First thanks for your reaction... I was having this idea to remove the @GeneretedValue since I don't really need a primary key in the DB. I use UUID as identification object and those are generated in client and save with every insert operation anyway. I guess my idea is to use an already generated ID(No need for Hibernate to handle that) and set the DB up to use the column as a primary key. What do you think about this idea?

Comment: That is exactly what I am suggesting.  Ideally you'd prefer to try and use a tuple of existing columns to avoid having to generate anything on the client end.  For example, one recent performance problem I saw was the time involved in Java generating random UUIDs.  Beware that using that technique on the client, while it minimizes the database network traffic overhead and allows you to batch insert; the cost of doing that type of operation isn't cheap; especially when we're talking about bulk copy operations here as we are.

Comment: What do you mean in the second sentence? Even if I set up existing columns i still have to batch insert the entity-objects. So I don't see anyway to gain performance here. By minimizing communication between server (at least on the sequence creation for each copied object as you developed in your first answer), I see a lot of potential regarding the number of handled objects. I can't think of removing the UUID as an attribute. It's the most important attribute and the client it seems to me, doesn't really spend time generating them. I least compared to the time spent on inserting the entities.

Comment: All I am saying is that generating a UUID sporadically isn't problematic; however when you profile that operation in something like a data load loop or where you might be constructing an object that uses it frequently, it can be a contention point for the JVM in terms of performance.  That's all.  If the UUID is already provided to you and you are not generating it, then may be fine.